# Q. How to get the status of block volume duplication

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can I know the logical copy completion of block volume duplication?
*The purpose is to restart the application DB after completing the logical copy.

I'd like to know whether it`s able to check with the following API or another API.

1. When the value of "number of active transaction" in source disk is 0. *
2. When API "Network_Storage::isDuplicateReadyToMount" indicates "true" at target disk .
3. When API "SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi::getVolumeStatus" indicates some value at source disk.

*displayed by "slcli block volume-detail" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know if the volume duplication was completed successfully you require to verify if there is not any active transaction on the storage volume.

1. This number of transactions should be 0 as you noticed.
2. This method only returns a boolean related to if a volume is ready to have Hosts authorized to access it, but it also states that "This does not indicate whether another operation may be blockings" and to better check volumeStatus, so it cannot verify if the storage volume has been provisioned completely.
3. This method returns a null if there is a transaction running on the specified volume and "PROVISION COMPLETED" value once successfully completion.

You may use SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getObject method over a block volume, if it wasn´t completed yet it will have a value different than 0 on activeTransactionsCount parameter and the object activeTransactions will display more info.

Try the following REST example:
method GET

```
https://[apiUsername]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storageId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,capacityGb,username,activeTransactionCount,activeTransactions, originalVolumeName,originalVolumeSize]
```

I would recommend the method above as this method is used by control portal and the SLcli.